# Why I have this problem with the appbundle?

Tags: react-native, key, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

I published this app on the playstore (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brawlcalculator) and I want to reduce the dimension of the app using an app bundle. I created the app with React Native and I used in the same project this command to create the apk(./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease) and I successfull published it into the playstore, then I created the app bundle with this command (./gradlew bundleDebug) and when I tried to upload the appbundle it gives me an error: "The appbundle have the wrong key". Does I have to upload the apk and the appbundle together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assembleRelease` signs the APK with your release key, while `bundleDebug` signs the Bundle with your debug key.

Instead, you should upload the Bundle built with your release key, which you can do using the `bundleRelease` task.

Comment: Does I need to load both apk and app bundle or I need to upload just one of them?

Comment: Just one of them. They're the same app under different formats. With the App Bundle, you just get more optimizations from Google Play.